# Entire arraylist keeps on being printed after being edited

Tags: java, arraylist

Not sure why, but the first time after printing out the data it only prints out the names with the votes one by one but after modifying it, it prints out the entire arraylist for some reason.

Tester class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ElectionTesterV4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0, counter = 0;
        ArrayList<Candidate4> c = new ArrayList<Candidate4>();

        Candidate4 John = new Candidate4("John Smith", 5000);
        c.add(John);
        Candidate4 Lucy = new Candidate4("Lucy Robertson", 8000);
        c.add(Lucy);
        Candidate4 Marie = new Candidate4("Marie Grace", 7000);
        c.add(Marie);
        Candidate4 Raymond = new Candidate4("Raymond Zhang", 10000);
        c.add(Raymond);
        Candidate4 JohnD = new Candidate4("John Doe", 2500);
        c.add(JohnD);
        Candidate4 JuanG = new Candidate4("Juan Garcia", 6000);

        System.out.println("Raw Election Data: ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for(Candidate4 ca : c) {
            System.out.println(ca.toString());
            sum += ca.getVotes();
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Election Results");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Candidate               Votes Received                      % of Total Votes");
        for(Candidate4 ca : c) {
            System.out.printf("%15s                %5d                         %2.2f\n", 
        ca.getName(), ca.getVotes(), ((double)ca.getVotes() / sum) * 100);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total number of votes cast in election is: "+sum);
        System.out.println();
        John.replaceName(JuanG);
        System.out.println();

        sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Raw Election Data: ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for(Candidate4 ca : c) {
            System.out.println(c.toString());
            sum += ca.getVotes();
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Election Results");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Candidate               Votes Received                      % of Total Votes");
        for(Candidate4 ca : c) {
            System.out.printf("%15s                %5d                         %2.2f\n", 
        ca.getName(), ca.getVotes(), ((double)ca.getVotes() / sum) * 100);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total number of votes cast in election is: "+sum);
        System.out.println();
        John.replaceVotes(6000);
        System.out.println();
        sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Raw Election Data: ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for(Candidate4 ca : c) {
            System.out.println(c.toString());
            sum += ca.getVotes();
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Election Results");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Candidate               Votes Received                      % of Total Votes");
        for(Candidate4 ca : c) {
            System.out.printf("%15s                %5d                         %2.2f\n", 
        ca.getName(), ca.getVotes(), ((double)ca.getVotes() / sum) * 100);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total number of votes cast in election is: "+sum);
    }
}
```

Methods class:

```
public class Candidate4 {
    // instance variables
    private int numVotes;
    private String name;

    // Constructor for objects of class Candidate
    public Candidate4(String name, int numVotes) {
        // initialize instance variables
        this.name = name;
        this.numVotes = numVotes;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getVotes() {
        return numVotes;
    }

    public void setVotes(int n) {
        numVotes = n;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " received " + numVotes + " votes.";
    }

    public void replaceName(String n) { //replaces name
        System.out.println("Changing " + name + "'s name to " + n);
        name = n;
    }

    public void replaceVotes(int v) { //replaces votes)
        System.out.println("Changing " + name + "'s votes to " + v);
        numVotes = v;
    }

    public void replaceName(Candidate4 c) { //replaces name
        System.out.println("Changing " + name + "'s name to " + c.getName());
        name = c.getName();
    }

    public void replaceVotes(Candidate4 c) { //switches votes
        System.out.println("Replacing " + name + "'s votes with " + c.getName());
        numVotes = c.getVotes();
    }
}
```

I have used code similar to this to print out arraylists object by object so I don't know why this time it keeps on printing out the entire arraylist every iteration in the loop.

Comment: In your prints you are doing this ```System.out.println(c.toString());```, it should be ```System.out.println(ca);``` as what @user7 commented below

Comment: @Mark Or just `System.out.println(ca)`

Comment: @user7 I think the OP will use ```System.out.println(ca.toString());``` since the OP's ```toString()``` method has special printing to be done

Comment: @Mark By default, it will call the `toString()` of the object that is being printed

Comment: @user7 I didn't know that. Thank you for the new knowledge!

Comment: Darnit yeah, it should be `System.out.println(ca.toString());`, simple error on my part

Comment: Also yes you would have to do `ca.toString()` since I do have a special printing method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakenly just put:

```
System.out.println(c.toString());
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(ca.toString());
```

Comment: No need to post it as an answer since it is already in the comment.